# How to emit source code creating proxy methods?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have some source code in string e.g.

```
string source = 
           "var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            var stack = new Stack<string>();
            var list = new List<string>() { };
            watch.Start();";
source = Emit(source);
```

I want the emitted source to be something like

```
                var watch = A();
                var stack = B();
                var list = C();
                D(watch);

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch A() 
{
     return new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
}
Stack<string> B() 
{
     return new Stack<string>();
}
List<string> C() 
{
     return new List<string>();
}
void D(System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch a) 
{
     a.Start();
}
```

This is implemented in some obfuscators, and if i remember is called proxy methods or something, it is the exact opposite of inlining. What would be the correct way to implement this? Expressions trees? Roslyn or System.Codedom or some other library?

Comment: I'd say Roslyn is your best bet. Parse the string into an AST (as yeoman mentioned below) so that you can easily work with the individual parts of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't have code as a string but as an AST (abstract syntax tree) build of types from the compiler / code generation library of your choice.

Such an AST you can then easily modify because it is an organized data structure instead of a string.